# Image not showing on my UIImageview after clicking on UICollectionview cell until scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

i need help regarding uicollectionview.I have an app with uicollectionview horizontal scrolling.The collectionview cell display images from array.when i clicked on any cell log show the cell index means cell get tapped.But the image on that cell did not display on my UIImageView until i scroll the collectionview.I just need when any cell get tapped, the tapped image show up on my UIimageview without scrolling the uicollectionview.Here is my Code

```
(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    _previewCoverImage.image=_objects[indexPath.row];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you click on any cell, save the index number and then call `[_itemsCollectionView reloadData]` and then in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method checks the clicked cell and whether `indexpath.row` is the same or not. If it's the same, then display:-

```
_previewCoverImage.image=_objects[indexPath.row];
```

Example:

```
int index = -1;

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  index = indexPath.row;
  [collectionView reloadData];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if(indexPath.row == index) {
    _previewCoverImage.image=_objects[indexPath.row];
  } else {
    // Display label with index number or whaterever you want
    // or you can just ignore else part.
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in code.How i can save the index number.I have already use [_itemsCollectionView reloadData] in this method.But no success

Comment: int index = -1;
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  index = indexPath.row;
 [collecctionView reloadData];
  }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   if(indexPath.row == index){

          _previewCoverImage.image=_objects[indexPath.row];

  }else{
//display label with index number or whaterever you want or you can just ignore else part.
}
}

Comment: Thanks for your help.But still no success.by using reloaddata method image pass to UIimageView but on double tap.I want this same work on single tap.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trying I finally got the solution. I just need to add the `reloadData` method in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Here is the code:

```
(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _previewCoverImage.image=_objects[indexPath.row];
    [_magCoverView reloadData];
  }
```

`_objects` is an array where you get the images and `_magCoverView` is a `collectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

(:-Hope it helps do like this//if any mistakes let me know guys.

```
BOOL isSelected;
unsigned short int selectedIndex;
//Declare like this in ViewController.h
//add following code in didSelectItem method
if(isSelected)
{
    [self reloadCell:selectedIndex];
}
isSelected=YES;
selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
///
-(void)reloadCell:(unsigned short int) index
{
    //you can call reload collection view cell here
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

    [serviceCollection performBatchUpdates:^{
        [serviceCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.But i have already solve this problem and update here new code.